# How to make sure that ansible playbook uses hostname from different file or uses it from command line?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that I run from below command line and it works fine.

```
ansible-playbook -e 'host_key_checking=False' -e 'num_serial=10' test.yml -u golden
```

It works on the hosts specified in `/etc/ansible/hosts` file. But is there any way to pass hostnames directly on the command line or generate new file with hostname line by line in it so that my ansible works on that hostnames instead of working from default `/etc/ansible/hosts` file?

Below is my ansible file:

```
# This will copy files
---
- hosts: servers
  serial: "{{ num_serial }}"
  tasks:
      - name: copy files to server
        shell: "(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.host.com 'ls -1 /var/lib/workspace/data/*' | parallel -j20 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.host.com:{} /data/holder/files/procs/')"

      - name: sleep for 3 sec
        pause: seconds=3
```

Now I wanted to generate new file which will have all the servers line by line and then my ansible play book work on that file instead? Is this possible?

I am running ansible 2.6.3 version.

Answer (score 2):

The question has been answered probably but will just answer again to add more points.

Always look for command line for help related to the arguments or any info needed.

```
ansible-playbook --help | grep inventory 

  -i INVENTORY, --inventory=INVENTORY, --inventory-file=INVENTORY
                        specify inventory host path or comma separated host
                        list. --inventory-file is deprecated
```

The support of ansible inventory in file format is with two extensions:

1. yml
2. ini --> specifying ini extension is not mandatory.

The [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) link provides more info on the format and should be referred before choosing any format to implement.

Adding @HermanTheGermanHesse answer's so that all the possible points are covered.

In case the above is not used/you don't want to use. Ansible at last will refer the ansible.cfg for the hosts and variable definition.

```
[defaults]
inventory = path/to/hosts
From here:
```

The ansible.cfg file will be chosen in this order:

1. ANSIBLE_CONFIG environment variable
2. /ansible.cfg
3. ~/.ansible.cfg
4. /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

Comment: Do you want to add my answer into yours? For completeness sake

Comment: @error404 That makes sense. If I pass hostnames like that in the command line with -i as the parameter then as of now it is complaining like this `[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: servers PLAY [servers] ******************************************************** skipping: no hosts matched`. Do I need to modify anything in my playbook so that -i parameter works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-i` flag to specify the inventory to use. For example:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts play.yml
```

Comment: what is this `hosts`? A new file with server line by line in it?

Comment: The `-i` also accepts a CSV of hostnames: `ansible-playbook -i 10.0.0.1,10.0.0.5,some-hostname-goes-here,192.168.99.100 the-playbook.yml` with the caveat that managing any host variables needs to be done either in the playbook or via a dynamic inventory mechanism

Comment: @AlassaneNdiaye Can I keep this new hosts file in my current directory where ansible playbook is sitting?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel That makes sense. If I pass hostnames like that in the command line with -i as the parameter then as of now it is complaining like this `[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: servers PLAY [servers] ******************************************************** skipping: no hosts matched`. Do I need to modify anything in my playbook so that -i parameter works?

Comment: @flash Yes, you must switch to `hosts: all`, currently your playbook only target hosts in the group `server`

Comment: @AlassaneNdiaye so if I switch to `hosts: all` in my playbook then what happens? Will it work only on those servers that I am passing on the command line? That's what it means?

Comment: @AlassaneNdiaye This is how I was running my playbook now - `ansible-playbook -e 'host_key_checking=False' -e 'num_serial=30' -i 'abc.com,def.com,pqr.com' test.yml -u golden` just fyi

Comment: `host: all` targets all hosts inside the inventory. You can find more info here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

Answer (score 1):

A way to specify the inventory file to use is to set `inventory` in the `ansible.cfg`-file as such:

```
[defaults]
inventory = path/to/hosts
```

From [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings):

The ansible.cfg file will be chosen in this order:

1. ANSIBLE_CONFIG environment variable
2. ./ansible.cfg
3. ~/.ansible.cfg
4. /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

   **EDIT**

From your comment:
`[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: servers PLAY [servers]`

It seems that ansible doesn't recognize hosts passed with the `-i` Flag as belonging to a group. Since you mentioned in chat that you generate a list with the passed hosts, I'd suggest creating a file where the list of hosts to passed is made to belong to a group callerd `[servers]` and passing the path to it with the `-i` Flag.

Comment: If I pass hostnames like that in the command line with -i as the parameter then as of now it is complaining like this `[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: servers PLAY [servers] ******************************************************** skipping: no hosts matched`. Do I need to modify anything in my playbook so that -i parameter works?

Comment: Where do you have your ansible config file?

Comment: It is at the default place `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` and I am running my playbook like this - `ansible-playbook -e 'host_key_checking=False' -e 'num_serial=30' -i abc.com def.com pqr.com test.yml -u golden`

Comment: From https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-i specify inventory host path or comma separated host list. –inventory-file is deprecated. Your hosts are not comma separated, also maybe try this ... -i "and.com,def.com,QPR.com"

Comment: oops sorry, i pasted it wrong. In real they are comma separated. Also I haven't modified anything in ansible.cfg file btw. I can try adding double quotes around host name. But is there anything I need to change in my playbook bcoz my playbook is referencing as `servers` to look in `/etc/ansible/hosts` file.

Comment: I ran again but it failed with same error message and didn't ran my playbook at all.

Comment: Why are you passing hosts with -i? Does your playbook have many host groups that it targets and you haven't chosen a host from each?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194511/discussion-between-flash-and-hermanthegermanhesse).